# Суммарное время работы устройств по событиям в БД MySQL

Tags: mysql

Контроллер пишет события включения/выключения устройств в базу в виде
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где 
pinID - пин контроллера на котором висит устройство
pinStatus - событие включения/выключения устройства(1-выкл / 0 -вкл)
datetime - время этого события
не обязательно две записи подряд будут относиться к одному устройству

как можно подсчитать суммарное время работы каждого устройства за определенный период?

Если взять во внимание, что в выключенном состоянии pinStatus = 1, а во включенном pinStatus = 0, то за период указанный в таблице, время работы устройства с pinID = 1:
начало периода -  2021-08-18 23:50:59
**выключение** pin1 - 2021-08-18 23:51:01 (+2 сек)

*включение* pin1 - 2021-08-19 00:08:33
**выключение** pin1 - 2021-08-19 00:08:36 (+3 сек)

*включение* pin1 - 2021-08-19 00:10:20
**выключение** pin1 - 2021-08-19 00:10:24 (+4 сек)

Хотелось бы запросом mysql получить строки вида:

pinID worktime
1     00:00:09
3     00:00:??
9     00:00:??
10    00:00:??
...
(значения посчитал только для первого пина)

Comment: mariadb -V
mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.29-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnueabihf (armv7l) using readline 5.2

Comment: напишите, пожалуйста,, исходя из данных на картинке, сколько работало устройство с пином 1

Comment: @nörbörnën, отредактировал вопрос, дополнил информацией касательно пина 1, большое спасибо за участие